# Slipping clutch on my Yahama YZF600R 2002 34,000km

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, yamaha

I just bought my Yamaha YZF600r about 2 months ago and at first I noticed first and sec were slipping and last night when I went for a ride I lost all power and had to pull over. Bike will start no problem, but when I put it in first gear I got nothing. It won’t go anywhere and I’ve tried it throughout all the gears and it still won’t move ... did I blow my clutch?

Comment: That sounds very likely...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you by chance change the oil in it since you've bought it? If so, *specifically* what oil did you use?

Comment: No I never did a oil change